# Mysql query result ouput outside of while {}

Tags: mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have a problem to get my sql query result fully working outside the while loop.

I have a query like this:

```
$result_artikel = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT oxtitle, FROM oxarticles a
INNER JOIN oxobject2category b ON a.oxid = b.oxobjectid
WHERE b.oxcatnid IN (SELECT oxcatnid FROM oxobject2category WHERE oxobjectid = '$term')ORDER BY oxtitle ASC")
or die(mysql_error());  ;
```

this gives back some names (oxtitle). For example 5:

Car,
Smartphone,
Chair,
Table,
Drink

in the next step I put this query results in an array and output them in the while loop

```
$Daten_artikel = array(
    'name' => '',
    'oxsort' => '',
    'bild' => ''
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_artikel))
{
    $Daten_artikel['name'] = $row['oxtitle'];
    $Daten_artikel['oxsort'] = $row['oxsort'];
    $Daten_artikel['bild'] = $row['oxpic1'];

    echo '<br>' . "Name: ".$Daten_artikel['name'];
}
```

The reason why I put the results in an array is that I can output them outside the while loop. This works so far, BUT when I output the result outside the while loop I have only one name (oxtitle) in the array. And this is my problem that I cant get fix.

I need the results outside the while loop cause I have later in the page a html table, that musst be filled by IF statement.

Exmaple:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php
if ($Daten_artikel['name'] == smartphone )
    {
    echo $Daten_artikel['name'];
    }
?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<?php
if ($Daten_artikel['name'] == chair)
    {
    echo $Daten_artikel['name'];
    }
?>
</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

This is just an exmaple. But this cant works, cause in the array are just one name (oxtitle) for example "car". So the if-statement cant work. It just works for: if array == car.

One soulution can be to put all my table html code with the if loops in the while loop. But this means that I musst work always inside the wile loop with echo '' and so on. And this not not so fine. I hope there is another soultion that I can it get work "my" way. Means that the array contains all name (oxtitles) even outside the while loop, so that I can work with if-statements.

Sorry for my bad english.
Greetz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use this

```
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_artikel) ;

  $Daten_artikel['name'] = $row['oxtitle'];
  $Daten_artikel['oxsort'] = $row['oxsort'];
  $Daten_artikel['bild'] = $row['oxpic1'];

 // echo '<br>' . "Name: ".$Daten_artikel['name'];
```

instead of while loop. and then you can use those variables.

EDIT:

```
 <?php
   echo "<table>";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_artikel))
{
$Daten_artikel['name'] = $row['oxtitle'];
$Daten_artikel['oxsort'] = $row['oxsort'];
$Daten_artikel['bild'] = $row['oxpic1'];

//echo '<br>' . "Name: ".$Daten_artikel['name'];
?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php
if ($Daten_artikel['name'] == "smartphone" )
{
echo $Daten_artikel['name'];
}
if ($Daten_artikel['name'] == "chair")
{
echo $Daten_artikel['name'];
}
else {echo "there is nothing";} 
?>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

EDIT2 ;
im not sure i understood you , but this soluion ,

change your order by to this:

```
   ORDER BY case when oxtitle = 'Schwarz' then 1
                 when oxtitle = 'Cyan'    then 2
                 when oxtitle = 'Magenta'    then 3
                 when oxtitle = 'Gelb'    then 4 end
```

and try this code:

```
    echo "<table>";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_artikel))
 {
  $Daten_artikel['name'] = $row['oxtitle'];
  $Daten_artikel['oxsort'] = $row['oxsort'];
  $Daten_artikel['bild'] = $row['oxpic1'];

  // echo '<br>' . "Name: ".$Daten_artikel['name'];
 ?>
  <tr>
  <td>xzy</td>
   <td>
     <?php
   echo $Daten_artikel['name'] ;

   ?>
   </td>
  </tr>

 <?php
   }
  echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

**EDIT3.**

```
  ORDER BY case when oxtitle like '%Schwarz%' then 1
             when oxtitle LIKE '%Cyan%'    then 2
             when oxtitle LIKE '%Magenta%'    then 3
             when oxtitle LIKE '%Gelb%'    then 4 end
```

**EDIT4:**
due to your needs 
use this

```
     case when oxtitle like '%Schwarz%' and (oxsort = 13 or oxsort = 3 ) then 1
     .....
```

Comment: This "echo" gives me just one name (Car) back. So my if-statemant cant work on this. It just work on: `if ($Daten_artikel['name'] == Car)
    {
    echo $Daten_artikel['name'];
    }`

Comment: This gives me again just one name back.

Comment: Or is there a complete other solution to make my query results working outside the while lopp?

Comment: ok try maybe this updated solution. this option is you will put the table inside the while loop

Comment: This works so far. not the best solution but it works. The only problem is now the sort of the rows. Can i make a sort independent of the sort in the query? F.E: Table always first, than Car, than Drink, than Chair....?

Comment: yes you can sort them as you want. just tell me how you want the result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34297/discussion-between-echo-me-and-kuba)

Comment: yeah, thats pretty close how i mean it. The problem is that the names are like "something schwarz" oder "something cyan". So i thing the "order by" that you made will not work. Not shure if you can "order by" by checking if the result (oxtitle) contains an word?!

Comment: thats great :) One thing left. Is it possible to make 2 statements for the "order by". I want to use the oxsort also for the "order by". Somethink like this: `ORDER BY case when oxtitle like '%Schwarz%' and oxsort = '13 or 3' then 1` I think thats possible but the question is if the query knows which oxsort belongs to which oxtitle. I mean the oxtitle, oxsort and oxpic that belongs togehter are of course in the same row in the table but the question is, if the query can handle that.

Comment: you can do it like that `case when oxtitle like '%Schwarz%' and (oxsort = 13 or oxsort = 3 ) then 1`

Comment: Works perfect. Thumbs ups and thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: of course :) Last question :) If i want to check if the oxtitle contains different words, how is the syntax? i tried this `when oxtitle like ('%Cyan% or %Magenta% or %something%') and (oxsort = 3 or oxsort 13 ) then 9` but it didnt works.

Comment: maybe you mean this? `when (oxtitle like '%Cyan% or oxtitle like  %Magenta% or oxtitle like %something%')  and (oxsort = 3 or oxsort 13 ) then 9`

Comment: didnt work but this works: `when (oxtitle like '%Cyan%' or oxtitle like '%Magenta%') and (oxsort = 13 or oxsort = 3) then 9`
The apostrophe musst to be for and after each %something%

Dont know how to thank yout for your time and patience. Is there somewhere an extra big thank you button?! :)

Comment: ahh sorry i made error apostrof , just correct apostrofs , i didnt see them

Comment: `when (oxtitle like '%Cyan%' or oxtitle like '%Magenta%' or oxtitle like '%something%') and (oxsort = 3 or oxsort 13 ) then 9`